# Hover text on plot incorrect

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotly

So I have a plot which show the actual value, modeled value and the error.Below is the code for the same.

```
library(plotly)
library(ggplot2)

ab <-tibble::tribble(
  ~modeled, ~actuals, ~weekenddate,  ~err,
    501384,   481864, "2014-02-02", 19519,
    488933,   479078, "2014-02-09",  9856,
    484191,   464026, "2014-02-16", 20165,
    480443,   460339, "2014-02-23", 20104,
    482512,   464021, "2014-03-02", 18491,
    488843,   462458, "2014-03-09", 26385
  )


test_bottom <- ggplot(ab, aes(x = weekenddate, y = actuals)) +
  geom_smooth(method = "lm", se = FALSE, color = "lightgrey") +  # Plot regression slope
  geom_segment(aes(xend = weekenddate, yend = modeled), alpha = .2) +  # alpha to fade lines
  # > Alpha adjustments made here...
  geom_point(aes(color = err)) +  # Alpha mapped to abs(residuals)
  scale_color_gradient2(low = "blue", mid = "white", high = "red") +
  guides(color = FALSE) +  # Alpha legend removed
  geom_point(aes(y = modeled), shape = 1) +
  theme_bw()

ggplotly(test_bottom)


<sup>Created on 2018-10-12 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>
```

[image]

If you see the hover it shows modeled and actual value both the same. The hover should just show modeled value and  red dot when hovered should show only the actual value along with the error.

How can this be done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solution is to define a `text` aesthetic in `ggplot` and then to specify in `ggplotly` that `text` must be shown in the tooltip.

```
library(plotly)
library(ggplot2)

ab <-tibble::tribble(
  ~modeled, ~actuals, ~weekenddate,  ~err,
    501384,   481864, "2014-02-02", 19519,
    488933,   479078, "2014-02-09",  9856,
    484191,   464026, "2014-02-16", 20165,
    480443,   460339, "2014-02-23", 20104,
    482512,   464021, "2014-03-02", 18491,
    488843,   462458, "2014-03-09", 26385
  )
names(ab)[4] <- "Error"

test_bottom <- ggplot(ab, aes(x = weekenddate, y = actuals, 
  text=paste0("Date:", weekenddate, "<br>Modeled:", modeled, "<br>Actuals:", actuals))) +
  geom_smooth(method = "lm", se = FALSE, color = "lightgrey") +
  geom_segment(aes(xend = weekenddate, yend = modeled), alpha = .2) +  
  geom_point(aes(color = Error)) +  
  scale_color_gradient2(low = "blue", mid = "white", high = "red") +
  guides(color = FALSE) + 
  geom_point(aes(y = modeled), shape = 1) +
  theme_bw()

ggplotly(test_bottom, tooltip=c("text","Error"))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you . But with this I cant see error values in tooltip when hovered on red icon  to display how much is the difference in actual and modeled values

Comment: Thank you. Is their a way I see the error only on the red circle and not on the black one.